Database for large matrix
I am trying to find a good database to save a large matrix. The matrix would be something of a 3000x3000.
The operations that are needed are fast reads of 1 specific item e.g. row 2 column 30. Another operations that should be as fast as possible is the update of the items full row and full column. If I update row 3 column 30, the entire row 3 and column 30 needs new values, so a fast way to do this would be handy. If an update of a single field is fast enough, maybe a batch update(full row and column) isn't needed.
I am struggling to find the right database and/or architecture to achieve something like this.
My first thought was storing this inside a mongoDb as a complete matrix. But this seems to be rather slow.
My second thought would be to store every value by a single item. e.g. I am just a little afraid this might bloat the database if 30 or more matrices have been added. And an update would mean updating 6000 items at once.

_id
column
row
value

Does any of you have a good solution or has build something for a similar case?
EDIT:
The matrix is a distance matrix, the matrix will just hold integer values en will be filled.
The system using the matrix will be used by multiple users, we are currently thinking of blocking operations in the code when multiple user want to have access or write to the matrix.
In a dream scenario updating a row and column would have to be below 100ms(for now I just try to aim as fast as possible and see where this brings me).
Because this is a distance matrix updating a single value never really happens, this would always lead to updating the entire column and the row.
Thank you for your time

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Does each row/column have a value of the same datatype? Is the number of rows and columns absolutely fixed?

Can the data be decomposed in any way

Best answer I could find - sometimes a spreadsheet is the optimal solution. What sort of data do you have? Is it time series?

You may want to add some details to your description: (1) Is the matrix filled or sparse, i.e. are there many cells without any value ? (2) Is this a multi-user system, i.e. multiple concurrent users/processes will read from the matrix and/or update the matrix ? (3) You mention performance. What are the requirements from that perspective: how long should one transaction (reading or updating) take at the maximum ?

I will make and edit to give more information about he data

What's your current method of updating your data? What are the MIN and MAX values of the integers?

@Vérace Currently everything is just saved as a json in a file,for very obious reason we want to move away from this method. The min would be 0 and the max is not clearly defined but would be somewhere around the lines of 22000. but more realisticly it would never be larger then 6000

In general, I would say that the RDBMS/SQL option given below by Gilbert feels like the correct one. But when it comes to bulk update/read operations - I would think that the NoSQL option with one-row-per-document (or one-column-per-doc) is faster for at least one type of update. And faster for row-reads & full-matrix reads. For a 3000 x 3000 matrix, I don't see how the DB engine accessing 9 million records would be faster than accessing 3000 documents, on equal hardware. (Still, it depends on requirements & potential optimisations others have asked about above.)

@aneroid "I don't see how the DB engine accessing 9 million records would be faster than accessing 3000 documents, on equal hardware." - FWIW, no reason it would necessarily be any slower either. At the end of the day, X amount of data to be read is going to take the same amount of time to load off disk, regardless if it's logically stored in a document or a table.

My €0.02 - PostgreSQL. Have functions over a given row_num and/or col_num. Postgresql has very good ARRAY capabilites for subsets of rows and columns - but up to 3000, not so sure - you'll have to test, but again, functions may help. There was SCIdb (now defunct) and a related PostgreSQL answer here from your humble servant - HTH!

Last word - look at the INTARRAY contrib module! Also pgvector (never used, but it bhas a lot of traction right now).

@Vérace Currently I am looking into the SQL and MongoDb options as these stacks are more well known within the team, When my comparison is finished I will try to make an extra comparison with PostgresSQL to get the complete overview.

Using a relational database, you can define a Cell table like this:
Cell
----
Matrix
Row
Column
Value

The primary key would be matrix, row, column. You would need an additional unique index on matrix, column, row.
It's straightforward to retrieve an individual cell, an entire row, or an entire column. A 3000 x 3000 matrix would require 9 million rows. Depending on which relational database you use, plan on using around 54 MB of disk storage for one matrix.
Since you mentioned storing multiple matrices in a Stack Overflow comment, I added a Matrix column.

I will give this approach a go an try to compare speeds with other solutions

Where do you get 6 bytes/record? My calculations are 36 bytes/record for PostgreSQL and double that for the table with (2 bytes/integer × 4) for the raw data + 24 bytes/record + 4 bytes page header = 36. The pk of (matrix_id, row, column) takes this to 59 bytes. 59 × 9m ~ 532MB for 1 matrix plus pk!


fast way to do this would be handy

Fast way to update whole row or whole column will be bulk insert target values in temp table and single update of target table with those values.
Here is the example
-- target table
create table matrix(id int primary key, col int, rw int, val char(10) primary key (id,col,rw))

-- temp table
create table #mat (col int, rw int, val char(10) primary key(col,rw))

-- bulk insert into temp table from the client
insert into #mat values ...

-- update column @col_to_update of target table
update matrix set val=(select val from #mat a where matrix.col=a.col and matrix.rw=a.rw)
where id=@mymatrix and col=@col_to_update

-- or update row @row_to_update of target table
update matrix set val=(select val from #mat a where matrix.col=a.col and matrix.rw=a.rw)
where id=@mymatrix and rw=@row_to_update


First, some FYI's:

And an update would mean updating 6000 items at once.

1. When there are multiple matrices, an update to one matrix row/column would not require updating 3000 → 6000 items. It would still be 3000 since the id of the matrix would remain the same.
2. Wrt storing them in MongoDB

My first thought was storing this inside a mongoDb as a complete matrix. But this seems to be rather slow.

Assuming these are 32-bit Int's Int32, just the data is 4 bytes * 9 million = 36 MB which is higher than the 16 MB document size limit. The document itself would be larger than that, approx 87 MB. So the default would be impossible. Using MongoDB GridFS to workaround the size limit this requires using file-like objects or bytes/binary data. So you would need to serialize/deserialize every matrix to/from bytes, and lose any ability to do single-value, single-row, single-column update operations. It would always have to be updating the whole matrix in the DB.

For a NoSQL solution, in MongoDB, what you could do is have one row per document (or one column per document):

_id: ObjectID
matrix_id: Int32
row_id: Int32

With a unique index on matrix_id & row_id: matrix_id_1_row_id_1


values: Array[Int32]

1. Inserting a full matrix would be something like:
db.collection.insertMany([
  { matrix_id: 1, row_id: 0, values: [1, 2, 3] },
  { matrix_id: 1, row_id: 1, values: [4, 5, 6] },
  { matrix_id: 1, row_id: 2, values: [7, 8, 9] }
])

2. Updating a full row would be simple, one updateOne statement affecting one document:
db.collection.updateOne({
  // matrix id & index of the row being replaced
  matrix_id: 1, row_id: 2
},
{ $set: { values: [97, 98, 99] } }
)

3. Updating a single element is also one updateOne statement affecting one document but requires a slicing and concatenating the values array, and putting the new value at the specific index. See this question on StackOverflow (disclaimer: mine) for how the single-element update would work.
Inserting the value 1000 in the 3rd column (col_idx=2) would be something like:
// col_idx = 2
// new_col_val = 1000
{
  $concatArrays: [
    { $slice: ["$values", "$$col_idx"] },  // before replacement
    ["$$new_col_val"],  // the replacement
    { $slice: ["$values", { $add: ["$$col_idx", 1] }, { $size: "$values" }] }  // after
  ]
}

4. Updating a whole column would require one updateMany() statement affecting many documents, taken from this StackOverflow answer (disclaimer: mine). The full-column update uses a similar query to the single-element update, but updates all the row-documents for that matrix.
So these would be moderately efficient queries, and if your use-case requires updating a full column more often than updating a full row, then flip the row/column idx & values usage above.

Updates:
5. Reading a full matrix:
5.1 To get the result as a matrix in one document (when it's <16 MB; not possible with large matrices):
db.collection.aggregate([
  // uncomment this to get a specific matrix
  // { $match: { matrix_id: 2 } },
  { $sort: { matrix_id: 1, row_id: 1 } },
  { $group: { _id: "$matrix_id", rows: { $push: "$values" } } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, matrix_id: "$_id", rows: 1 } }
])

5.1 To get the result by row of the matrix, one doc per row:
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { matrix_id: 2 } },
  { $sort: { row_id: 1 } },
  { $project: { _id: 0 } }
])


This is an interresting and detailled approach I will definitly give it a try. In my use case the matrix is a distance matrix so updating 1 elemnt or just 1 row never happens it always will be a full column and a full row at once.. This operations will happend frequently

@BrechtVandenHouwe So in this solution, updating one full row would be very fast - single statement affecting single document. And updating one full column would be reasonably fast - single statement affecting multiple documents. That will require using Transactions to ensure read-consistency until the updateMany finishes updating all 3000 row-documents for that column. Wrt flipping row-documents vs column-documents: If both happen equally frequently, using row-documents is more natural but not a rule/guideline.

Where do you get Assuming these are 32-bit Int's Int32, each matrix is 4 bytes * 9 million = 36 MB which is higher than the 16 MB document size limit. from? With PostgreSQL, I constructed a 3000 x 40 matrix on dbfiddle.uk - I then measured its size on dbfiddle and by my calculations, if I had scaled it up by 3000 x 3000 with a Primary Key (Matrix_id (2 Bytes), row (2), column (2)), it's up to 530 MB all in - data + index! Now, I know that PostgreSQL isn't the best db for overhead/record, but surely you're not saying that there's no overhead with storage? Indexing?

@Vérace I should have said at least 36 MB. I was referring to the document-size itself being well beyond MongoDB's 16 MB document-size limit and hence not storable as a single document. So adding the data-structure & storage overhead would be even further beyond the document-size limit. But good catch, I will add some clarity. Anyway, I decided to measure the actual size of storing a full-matrix as 3000 documents with 3000 values each; comes to 45 MB "compressed", 87 MB uncompressed, which includes one compound index {matrix_id: 1, row_id: 1} and the default _id PK, total <100 KB.

Fair point - maybe I'm just a clarity pedant? :-) Your results correspond with the results here - PostgreSQL takes about 5x the space as does MongoDB. I can only assume that some sort of columnar store on PostgreSQL would do much better? Timescale has this (run-length), as does Greenplum, Citus  & Hydra (not sure of algorithms)...

... It's a very interesting (code for... ahem... thorny, difficult, controversial...) debate. Basically, the argument goes something like this ... we're schemaless and flexible vs but we do joins, and personally, for me, the whole point of having data is to do joins.

@Vérace At least debates like these are constructive when everyone brings the facts & figures :-) One of the core factors of NoSQL/DocStorage vs SQL/RDBMS schemas is the purpose of the data. ("Schema-less" is a very inaccurate and unfortunate historical term.) In NoSQL, or at least MongoDB & Document stores, the schema (which they most certainly do have) is based on how the data is going to be accessed. Whereas in RDBMS, it's data organised for *any* kind of access or in the most standardised way for the data; 3NF etc.

@Vérace Taking the OP's scenario - if the matrix was going to be at most 200 x 200, then for MongoDB, I would 100% say that the whole matrix should be stored as one document. Because it would fit and all update operations would be equally fast. But for PostgreSQL, etc. the correct schema would almost always be matrix_id, row_id, col_id, value because that is the cleanest/normalised form; whether it's for 200x200 or 3000x3000. On the other hand, a 2_000_000 x 2_000_000 matrix wouldn't fit with my Mongo proposal and would need a re-structure, while the RDBMS schema remains unchanged.

@aneroid while the RDBMS schema remains unchanged - which is part of the beauty of the RDBMS - your PHB comes  to you and says "That report is great, but I now need x, y & z, and while you're at  it, why not throw in the kitchen sink as well!". I know that MongoDB has its fans so it must work for them - I just prefer the flexibility that an RDBMS gives me - and yes, sometimes changing the schema can be a pain, but so can rearranging a MongoDB schema if the size of the document changes. The system (i.e. SE here) is griping about chatting too much - but watch this space...
